# Is there a way to animate the 3 icons of the page only when in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-waypoints, anime.js

From the webpage: http://supply54.herokuapp.com/ there are 3 icons that I would like to animate when scroll into view. However, I have tried multiple way of code, I do not know how to:
+ loop the code (if any sort of looping is possible, refer to my code below)
+ animate them differently

This is what I have tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home-icon').waypoint(function(){
        let cssTransforms = anime({
            targets: ['knight-icon', 'people-icon', 'globe-icon'],
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            translateY: [100, 0],
            opacity: [0, 1],
            delay: 500,
        });
        this.destroy();
    })
})
```

also

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let waypoint1 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.querySelector('#globe-icon'),
        handler: function() {
            anime({
                targets: '#globe-icon',
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                translateY: [100, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1],
                delay: 500,
            });
            this.destroy();
        },
        context: document.querySelector('.about'),
        offset: '100%',
    });
    let waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.querySelector('#poeple-icon'),
        handler: function() {
            anime({
                targets: '#poeple-icon',
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                translateY: [100, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1],
                delay: 500,
            });
            this.destroy();
        },
        context: document.querySelector('.work'),
        offset: '100%',
    });
    let waypoint3 = new Waypoint({
        element: document.querySelector('#knight-icon'),
        handler: function() {
            anime({
                targets: '#knight-icon',
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                translateY: [100, 0],
                opacity: [0, 1],
                delay: 500,
            });
            this.destroy();
        },
        context: document.querySelector('.modus'),
        offset: '100%',
    });
});
```

This is the html part of it.

```
<section class="about normal">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center section-title">ABOUT US</h2>
        <p class="section-description">We represent a worldwide network of reliable partners in the petroleum in the petroleum industry that has been built up over many years of solidifying our reputation. We go the extra mile for our partners, especially within the Southeast Asian and European region. Our core products are within the paraffin, base oil, hydraulic oil and HSD industries.</p>
            <div class="text-center animated-icon image-globe" id="animated-icon">
                <img src="./images/icon-globe.png" alt="Globe Icon" class="home-icon" id="globe-icon">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<section class="work normal">
    <h2 class="text-center section-title">HOW WE WORK</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="section-description">Supply 54 serves as mediators between an extensive portfolio of suppliers and consumers within our key markets. We thrive on optimizing partnerships through highly efficient and dynamic ways in today's hyper connected world.</p>
        <div class="text-center animated-icon image-links">
            <img src="./images/icon-people.png" alt="People Icon" class="home-icon" id="people-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="modus normal">
    <h2 class="text-center section-title">OUR MODUS OPERANDI</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="section-description">With effective costing, reliability and quality constantly being the basis of our operations, we benefit from long-term and satisfactory cooperation with our clients.</p>
        <div class="text-center animated-icon image-knight">
            <img src="./images/icon-knight.png" alt="Reliability & Quality" class="home-icon" id="knight-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Since there are 3 different sections, I would like each of the icon of each section to "ease-in" when the particular section is in view port. However, what I am now getting is just the first icon to be animated whereas the other 2 stays static(immovable), also the animation starts when the page loads. Do go to the webpage for actual view.